# Why is the graph returning different results

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Why does https://graph.facebook.com/http://www.clickconsult.com/ just return a number of shares where as https://graph.facebook.com/http://www.central-health.com returns an array of information about the website?

Comment: The clickconsult.com does not return any data when I look at it. This is probably your issue.

Comment: Strange, when I click it I get the following...

{
   "id": "http://www.clickconsult.com/",
   "shares": 37
}

Comment: Yes. The object can still exist even though the URL isn't sending any data.